# Read and straighten multiple images from vector string, get error: "vector subscript out of range" [c++]

Tags: c++, opencv

Hey I try to load all images from folder then straighten them and then imwrite all new images to new folder. My code works but not all is fine. On 4-5 images program crashed and I get back error message:

"Debug Asseration Failed! (...) Line:1201 Expression: vector subscript out of range"

This is my part of code:

```
int main()
{
system("dir Klasa_pierwsza\\*.tiff /b > lista_zdjęć.txt");
add_list_of_names_images_tiff_to_string_vector("lista_zdjęć.txt", lista);
display(lista);

std::vector<cv::Point> wektor_straighten_images2;

cv::Mat *M = new Mat[lista.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
{

    M[i] = imread("Klasa_pierwsza\\" + lista[i]);

    cv::cvtColor(M[i], bw, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::blur(bw, bw, cv::Size(3, 3));
    cv::Canny(bw, bw, 100, 100, 3); // 200

    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
    cv::HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 70, 30, 10);
    cv::Vec4i v1 = lines[3]; // lines[2,5,10

    wektor_straighten_images2.push_back(cv::Point(v1[0], v1[1]));
    wektor_straighten_images2.push_back(cv::Point(v1[2], v1[3]));

    cv::line(M[i], cv::Point(v1[0], v1[1]), cv::Point(v1[2], v1[3]), CV_RGB(0, 255, 0)); // rysowanie linii na obrazku im0

    double angle = std::atan((double)(wektor_straighten_images2[0].y - wektor_straighten_images2[1].y) / (wektor_straighten_images2[0].x - wektor_straighten_images2[1].x)) * (180 / CV_PI);

    cv::Point2f center(M[i].cols / 2., M[i].rows / 2.);
    cv::Mat dst, r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
    cv::warpAffine(M[i], dst, r, M[i].size());

    cv::imwrite("Zapisane\\" + lista[i], dst);
}
```

This is my function "add_list_of_names_images_tiff_to_string_vector"

```
void add_list_of_names_images_tiff_to_string_vector(String k,vector<string> &wektor)
{
ifstream in(k);
    if (!in) 
    {
        cout << "Can't read.\n";
    }
char str[255];

    while (in) 
    {
        in.getline(str, 255);
        wektor.push_back(str);
    }
    wektor.pop_back();

in.close();
}
```

Maybe someone have a good tips for me. Please help.

Why I do this? : I must create program to straighten all images from folder, but names of images are unknown.

EDIT:

Hmm problem is here: 
    cv::Vec4i v1 = lines[3];

but what kind of problem?

Comment: Find which line is throwing the error and fix your logic accordingly

Comment: Before doing `pop_back` check vector is not empty, and when using `[]` check index is in range

Comment: please, *never* use your native language or characterset for functions, file names, or comments. folks here can't read it, and also imread() will fail on non-ascii filenames.

Comment: Berak good note I correct it.

Comment: also, opencv has a nice [glob function](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp#L231) to traverse directories , and retrieve a `vector<String>`. better avoid rolling your own there !

Comment: I delete code inside:  M[i] = imread("Klasa_pierwsza\\" + lista[i]); and  cv::imwrite("Zapisane\\" + lista[i], M[i]); and program works fine. I'dont understand whats wrong are there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the problems in your code is, that you never check the results of your operations, there should be:

```
M[i] = imread("Klasa_pierwsza\\" + lista[i]);
if ( M[i].empty() )
{
     cerr << "Klasa_pierwsza\\" + lista[i] << " could not be loaded !" << endl;
     continue;
}

// ...

std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
cv::HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 70, 30, 10);
if ( lines.size() < 4 )
{
     cerr << "Klasa_pierwsza\\" + lista[i] << " did not have 4 lines !" << endl;
     continue;
}
cv::Vec4i v1 = lines[3]; // you have an access violation (out of bounds) here.
```

Comment: Super, thank You :) I see my problem, It's problem with image with number 4, 7 and 10 :)